ODE and Implicit Function Theorem
Is my approach right to this question?

Let $F: U \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function in a open set $U$, let $(t_0, x_0, y_0)$ be a point in $U$ such that $F(t_0, x_0, y_0) = 0$ and let $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(t_0,x_0,y_0) \neq 0$. Prove that, for every $\epsilon > 0$ small enough, there is a unique function $\phi: (t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(t_0) = x_0$, $\phi'(t_0) = y_0$ and $$ F(t, \phi(t), \phi'(t)) = 0 \, , \, \forall t \in (t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon).$$

My ideia was to use Implicit Function Theorem to find an open neighborhood V of $(t_0, x_0)$ and a $C^1$ real function $G$ defined in V such that for every $(t,x) \in V$, $G(t,x)$ is the unique real number such that $F(t,x,G(t,x)) = 0$.
So fix some $\delta > 0$ such that the closed square $K := \{ (t,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, : \, \max\{ |t - t_0|, |x - x_0| \} \leq \delta \}$ is contained in V. Let $M(\delta) := sup_{ (t,x) \in K} |G(t,x)|$, and let
$$\phi: (t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R} \, ; \, t \mapsto x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t G(s, x_0) ds,$$
for $\epsilon > 0$ small enough such that for every $t \in (t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon)$, we have $(t,x_0) \in K$.
We have $\phi(t_0) = x_0$ and $\phi'(t_0) = y_0$.
Now for $\epsilon \leq \frac{\delta}{M(\delta)}$,
$$ | \phi(t) - x_0 | \leq \int_{t_0}^t |G(s,x_0)| ds \leq M(\delta) \epsilon \leq \delta.$$
And for $\epsilon \leq \delta$,
$$ |t - t_0| \leq \delta.$$
Hence for $\epsilon$ small enough, for every $t \in (t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon)$,
$$ (t, \phi(t)) \in K \subset V.$$
Now is missing to prove that for every such $t$,
$$ F(t, \phi(t), \phi'(t)) = 0,$$
equivalentely,
$$G(t, \phi(t)) = \phi'(t) = G(t,x_0).$$
But I'm struggling in how to do it.
Thanks.

You are on the right track.
The implicit function theorem shows the existence of an open set $V=(t_0-\eta,t_0+\eta) \times (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ and a unique function $G:V \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(t,x,G(t,x)) = 0$ for all $(t,x) \in V$.
To show the existence of a $\phi$, consider the ODE defined by
$\phi'(t) = G(t,\phi(t))$, $\phi(t_0)=x_0$, this ODE satisfies the usual existence & uniqueness hypotheses of Picard Lindelöf and hence the exists some interval $I=(t_0-\eta',t_0+\eta')$ and a $\phi:I \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the ODE. Then $F(t,\phi(t),\phi'(t)) = 0$ for $t \in I$.
Any other solution that satisfies the conditions satisfies the same ODE hence the $\phi$ is unique.
